# Web front end for Python script

Tags: python, networking

I have a Python script doing the grunt work of my motion tracking program. I have an OpenCV program sending coordinate data (integers) to my Python script.

I would like a very simple web page, one with 4-5 buttons which sends it to the python script for processing.

I'd prefer the web page be lightweight and compatible with mobile devices. I just need something very simple to send commands via tcp, rpc, or whatever means. I'm seeing lots of frameworks and the like, it seems a bit overkill to me for something static and simple.

OpenCV    -\
            
cedar-sentinel.py -> motors 
Web page -/

Web page ideals has Left, Right, Fast, Slow, Toggle Tracking State as buttons that send information (commands, IDs, something identifying of button pressed) to cedar-sentinel.py.

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Bottle: http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/

Answer (score 2):

Well the simplest is probably just old school [CGI.](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html)